# Strange cookies attached to my domain

Tags: cookies

We're having users occasionally complain about 400 Bad Requests when hitting our site. I've narrowed the problem down to the cookie header being > 8k which haproxy and nginx don't like.

A band-aid fix would be to double the request buffer sizes in haproxy and nginx, but what I'm really wondering is where are all these cookies are coming from? We (intentionally) send a very small number of cookies, and I'm baffled by some of the cookies being sent by users who have this problem:

eg. 
__insp_norec_sess=true

mp_f71c19735fa6ecc5225ff563285e1794_mixpanel=somelongvalue

amplitude_idmycompanyname=somelongvalue

etc.

How are our server sending these cookies and how do I trace the source of them?

**Update**:

So our internal app loads the html of pages that we scraped in an iframe. I had set allow-scripts on the iframe by default, so I'm guessing that the scraped pages were running some JS that was setting cookies on our domain (rather than on the sites domain).

This explains why users from within our office were running into the 400 Bad Requests. However, it in no way explains why clients who only hit our external site would run in to this problem. I'll have to wait until I get more concise reports from external users.

Comment: What domain created these cookies? The Firebug plugin for Firefox should have a Cookies tab, allowing you to inspect cookie information. The domain name could give you a clue. It's likely to be an advertisement or a tracking cookie, from my experience.

Comment: My domain created them!

We also have an internal app that loads pages in an iframe; I'm thinking that may be part of the problem.

It would explain why internal users run into this issue, but would not explain it for external users.

Comment: Does your site have advertisements on it? Do you use something like Google Analytics to track usage? Try removing these iframes one at a time until the cookies don't get created anymore.

Comment: You also might want to open the browser debugging console and watch the Network tab to see what JavaScript files are being downloaded, and what the domain names of those files are.